# Is it possible to get the android advertising id without adding play services ads dependency?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-advertising-id

I am using the google play ads dependency  just to get the advertising id.

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0

Is there any way to avoid this as the library has a method count of 6201.

Comment: Not all of GPS is proguaded. Click on "external" libs from the left hand side and you can see which module that `AdvertisingId` will be in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[AdvertisingIdClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient) and its associated classes are also found in the much smaller

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0
```

if you use Google Play services 8.3. Prior to that point, you are correct in that it was part of `play-services-ads`.

In any case, it is strongly recommended that you use [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to remove unused code from your app before shipping retail versions of your app.